# Access Sharepoint webservice from Silverlight with specfic user credentials

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint

I am accessing Sharepoint web services from a Silverlight application, I have put the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the root of my Sharepoint site, so I can access fine.

What I would like to do though is hard code the user credentials so the web service always connects with the same user.

Is this possible and if so how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After emailing Tim Heuer, I was informed that is not possible in SL3, but will be in SL4!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After emailing Tim Heuer, I was informed that is not possible in SL3, but will be in SL4!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently ran into similar case where I need to pass a specific credential to the generated web service client proxy in Silverlight 4 OOB.   For whatever reason I am still getting prompted for authentication so, I'm not sure if it's there in SL4.

What I know possible in SL4 is you can force an HttpRequest to use a ClientHttp stack instead of the WebBrowser one.  I've used this with SharePoint 2010 OData feed (_vti_bin/listdata.svc) before successfully, but to access SharePoint Web Services (for example: _vti_bin/lists.asmx), it's a different story.

I finally decided to create my own workaround (specific to SL OOB w/ Elevated Privilege) for this that should work on SL3 OOB and SL4 OOB with elevated privilege.  Basically creating my own SharePoint Web Service proxy using the ClientHttp stack and composing and passing my own SOAP message manually using WebRequest.

I blogged about how to do this [here](http://geeks.netindonesia.net/blogs/jimmy/archive/2011/03/23/how-to-call-sharepoint-web-service-with-specific-credential-from-silverlight-oob.aspx).